# Directed Hausdorff distance in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, distance, geos

I was wondering how to implement a directed (or one-sided) Hausdorff distance function in PostGIS?

I looked into the [PostGIS 2.3.3 source code](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/9ca34e6790224fd00c65aff1c82cd91ca396455f/postgis/lwgeom_geos.c#L164), and it seems that [ST_HausdorffDistance](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_HausdorffDistance.html) is implemented as a simple C wrapper function that calls the corresponding GEOS function as follows:

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(hausdorffdistance);
Datum hausdorffdistance(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    GSERIALIZED *geom1;
    GSERIALIZED *geom2;
    GEOSGeometry *g1;
    GEOSGeometry *g2;
    double result;
    int retcode;

    POSTGIS_DEBUG(2, "hausdorff_distance called");

    geom1 = PG_GETARG_GSERIALIZED_P(0);
    geom2 = PG_GETARG_GSERIALIZED_P(1);

    if ( gserialized_is_empty(geom1) || gserialized_is_empty(geom2) )
        PG_RETURN_NULL();

    initGEOS(lwpgnotice, lwgeom_geos_error);

    g1 = (GEOSGeometry *)POSTGIS2GEOS(geom1);
    if ( 0 == g1 )   /* exception thrown at construction */
    {
        HANDLE_GEOS_ERROR("First argument geometry could not be converted to GEOS");
        PG_RETURN_NULL();
    }

    g2 = (GEOSGeometry *)POSTGIS2GEOS(geom2);
    if ( 0 == g2 )   /* exception thrown */
    {
        HANDLE_GEOS_ERROR("Second argument geometry could not be converted to GEOS");
        GEOSGeom_destroy(g1);
        PG_RETURN_NULL();
    }

    retcode = GEOSHausdorffDistance(g1, g2, &result);
    GEOSGeom_destroy(g1);
    GEOSGeom_destroy(g2);

    if (retcode == 0)
    {
        HANDLE_GEOS_ERROR("GEOSHausdorffDistance");
        PG_RETURN_NULL(); /*never get here */
    }

    PG_FREE_IF_COPY(geom1, 0);
    PG_FREE_IF_COPY(geom2, 1);

    PG_RETURN_FLOAT8(result);
}
```

I don't have much experience with GEOS or interfacing it with PostGIS. The only thing I found in GEOS is that in that in [geos::algorithm::distance::DiscreteHausdorffDistance](http://geos.refractions.net/ro/doxygen_docs/html/classgeos_1_1algorithm_1_1distance_1_1DiscreteHausdorffDistance.html#_details), it is said that there is an `double orientedDistance ()` member function. I am not sure if the documentation is even current.

Can some with the knowledge suggest how to adapt the above code to obtain the directed (or one-sided) Hausdorff distance from GEOS?

--EDIT--

The PostGIS info from `SELECT postgis_full_version();'` is as below (Ubuntu 16.04).

> POSTGIS="2.3.3 r15473" GEOS="3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1 r4246" SFCGAL="1.2.2"
>   PROJ="Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.3, released
>   2015/09/16" LIBXML="2.9.3" LIBJSON="0.11.99" (core procs from "2.3.2
>   r15302" need upgrade) TOPOLOGY (topology procs from "2.3.2 r15302"
>   need upgrade) RASTER (raster procs from "2.3.2 r15302" need upgrade)
>   (sfcgal procs from "2.3.2 r15302" need upgrade)

Comment: What version of GEOS are you using, paste the output of `SELECT postgis_full_version();`

Comment: @EvanCarroll Please see the update for the PostGIS/GEOS versions.

Comment: I'm confused at the problem now. You're using PostGIS 2.3.3 why don't you just use the hausdorffdistance function in PostGIS? I don't get what you're trying to do.

Comment: @EvanCarroll The Hausdorff distance is a real distance, and symmetric. I only needed the one-sided Hausdorff distance, which is asymmetric. Please see e.g.: http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/cg-projects/98/normand/main.html for definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're talking about but the GEOS implimentation is pretty straight forward,

```
int GEOS_DLL GEOSHausdorffDistance(
   const GEOSGeometry *g1,
   const GEOSGeometry *g2,
   double *dist
);
```

That is to say, it takes geometry's and mutates a pointer to a double returning an int that represents status. There are no extra arguments. There are no methods of telling it "asymmetric" or "symmetric" or "one-sided". So fullstop, if you're using GEOS you're using, [DiscreteHausdorffDistance.cpp](https://github.com/OSGeo/geos/blob/5a730fc50dab2610a9e6c037b521accc66b7777b/src/algorithm/distance/DiscreteHausdorffDistance.cpp)

You can see the implementation here,

- [DiscreteHausdorffDistance.h](https://github.com/OSGeo/geos/blob/5a730fc50dab2610a9e6c037b521accc66b7777b/include/geos/algorithm/distance/DiscreteHausdorffDistance.h#L59)
- [DiscreteHausdorffDistance.cpp](https://github.com/OSGeo/geos/blob/5a730fc50dab2610a9e6c037b521accc66b7777b/src/algorithm/distance/DiscreteHausdorffDistance.cpp)

## Update

I think you're *way* over your head with this, but here is the breakdown of the source.

### PostGIS Bindings

There are two functions in PostGIS, you can see them made available to the user [here](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/976dcf593c687a2acaf2f1087cb85184773717ec/postgis/postgis.sql.in#L3344)

1. `ST_HausdorffDistance(geom1 geometry, geom2 geometry)`

   1. which dispatches to [`hausdorffdistance`](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/9ca34e6790224fd00c65aff1c82cd91ca396455f/postgis/lwgeom_geos.c#L171).
   2. `hausdorffdistance` references [`GEOSHausdorffDistance`](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/9ca34e6790224fd00c65aff1c82cd91ca396455f/postgis/lwgeom_geos.c#L205).
2. `ST_HausdorffDistance(geom1 geometry, geom2 geometry, float8)`

   1. which dispatches to [`hausdorffdistancedensify`](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/9ca34e6790224fd00c65aff1c82cd91ca396455f/postgis/lwgeom_geos.c#L229).
   2. `hausdorffdistancedensify` function references [`GEOSHausdorffDistanceDensify`](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/9ca34e6790224fd00c65aff1c82cd91ca396455f/postgis/lwgeom_geos.c#L264).

### LibGEOS

LibGEOS provides two corresponding functions

1. [`GEOSHausdorffDistance(const Geometry *g1, const Geometry *g2, double *dist)`](https://github.com/OSGeo/geos/blob/5a730fc50dab2610a9e6c037b521accc66b7777b/capi/geos_c.cpp#L287)

   1. `GEOSHausdorffDistance` dispatches to [`GEOSHausdorffDistance_r`](https://github.com/OSGeo/geos/blob/5a730fc50dab2610a9e6c037b521accc66b7777b/capi/geos_ts_c.cpp#L1199)
   2. `GEOSHausdorffDistance_r`'s implementation ultimately invokes [`DiscreteHausdorffDistance::distance(*g1, *g2)`](https://github.com/OSGeo/geos/blob/5a730fc50dab2610a9e6c037b521accc66b7777b/capi/geos_ts_c.cpp#L1217)
2. [`GEOSHausdorffDistanceDensify(const Geometry *g1, const Geometry *g2, double densifyFrac, double *dist)`](https://github.com/OSGeo/geos/blob/5a730fc50dab2610a9e6c037b521accc66b7777b/capi/geos_c.cpp#L293)

   1. `GEOSHausdorffDistanceDensify` dispatches to [`GEOSHausdorffDistanceDensify_r`](https://github.com/OSGeo/geos/blob/5a730fc50dab2610a9e6c037b521accc66b7777b/capi/geos_ts_c.cpp#L1233)
   2. `GEOSHausdorffDistanceDensify_r`'s implementation ultimately invokes [`DiscreteHausdorffDistance::distance(*g1, *g2, densifyFrac)`](https://github.com/OSGeo/geos/blob/5a730fc50dab2610a9e6c037b521accc66b7777b/capi/geos_ts_c.cpp#L1251)

## `DiscreteHausdorffDistance::distance`

Now you can see all roads end up at `DiscreteHausdorffDistance::distance` which is overloaded.

- 2 argument: [`double DiscreteHausdorffDistance::distance(const geom::Geometry& g0,                           const geom::Geometry& g1)`](https://github.com/OSGeo/geos/blob/5a730fc50dab2610a9e6c037b521accc66b7777b/src/algorithm/distance/DiscreteHausdorffDistance.cpp#L67)
- 3 argument: [`double DiscreteHausdorffDistance::distance(const geom::Geometry& g0, const geom::Geometry& g1, double densifyFrac)`](https://github.com/OSGeo/geos/blob/5a730fc50dab2610a9e6c037b521accc66b7777b/src/algorithm/distance/DiscreteHausdorffDistance.cpp#L76)

Both of those

1. create a [DiscreteHausdorffDistance](https://github.com/OSGeo/geos/blob/5a730fc50dab2610a9e6c037b521accc66b7777b/include/geos/algorithm/distance/DiscreteHausdorffDistance.h#L100)
2. Call [`distance`](https://github.com/OSGeo/geos/blob/5a730fc50dab2610a9e6c037b521accc66b7777b/include/geos/algorithm/distance/DiscreteHausdorffDistance.h#L138) on the object they create.
3. `distance` calls [`computeOrientedDistance(g0, g1, ptDist)` and `computeOrientedDistance(g1, g0, ptDist)`](https://github.com/OSGeo/geos/blob/5a730fc50dab2610a9e6c037b521accc66b7777b/include/geos/algorithm/distance/DiscreteHausdorffDistance.h#L224) which is defined [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/geos/blob/5a730fc50dab2610a9e6c037b521accc66b7777b/src/algorithm/distance/DiscreteHausdorffDistance.cpp#L87)
4. `computeOrientedDistance` mutates a private `ptDist` by calling `ptDist.setMaximum`

So the answer to your question: `computeOrientedDistance` is already called by both `ST_HausdorffDistance`. If you want a directional version, like [computeOrientedDistance](https://github.com/OSGeo/geos/blob/5a730fc50dab2610a9e6c037b521accc66b7777b/include/geos/algorithm/distance/DiscreteHausdorffDistance.h#L144) I think you'll have to pull the above apart and patch it in LibGEOS via a new `DiscreteHausdorffDistance::orientedDistance` and then into PostGIS. Or draw up a test suite and pay a consultant. While there are probably a *few* other software programmers here that could do it, it's way out of the expertise of this community ([Paul Ramsey](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/457/paul-ramsey) being an obvious exception, etc).

Generally, we don't implement software suggestions on GIS.SE. At least, I don't see that activity if it happens. We answer them with software already developed. The short answer here is that it's not done.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. In  DiscreteHausdorffDistance.h: `double orientedDistance() {
  computeOrientedDistance(g0, g1, ptDist);
  return ptDist.getDistance();
}` seem interesting. Do you know what it is and how to expose it to PostGIS for testing?

Comment: @tinlyx updated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first expose the "oriented" as a new CAPI function, then you would use the new function from postgis (will depend on new GEOS release)

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate the process a bit or provide a link? I'm not very familiar with it.