# How do I patch libgeos without losing QGIS?

Tags: open-source-gis, ubuntu, geos

How can I create a custom `libgeos` to replace the one in my Ubuntu system?

Basically, I'm trying to expose some of GEOS functions (`orientedDistance()`) to  other packages as explained in [Directed Hausdorff distance in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253067).

I guess I can trying compiling GEOS from source. But the problem is that, *even if I succeed* in figuring out a patch for exposing the function, I don't know how to replace the current `libgeos` in my system without breaking things.

To test, I tried removing the Ubuntu provided package with

```
sudo apt-get remove libgeos-3.5.1 libgeos-c1v5 -s
```

Then from the result below, I can see that most of the GIS packages I need will be gone:

```
...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 35 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Remv qgis-plugin-grass [1:2.99.0+git20170820+f867b65+24xenial-ubuntugis]
Remv qgis-provider-grass [1:2.99.0+git20170820+f867b65+24xenial-ubuntugis]
Remv qgis [1:2.99.0+git20170820+f867b65+24xenial-ubuntugis]
Remv python-qgis [1:2.99.0+git20170820+f867b65+24xenial-ubuntugis]
Remv python-qgis-common [1:2.99.0+git20170820+f867b65+24xenial-ubuntugis]
Remv gdal-bin [2.2.1+dfsg-2~xenial0]
Remv grass-core [7.2.1-1~xenial4]
Remv postgresql-9.6-pgrouting [2.4.1-1~exp1.pgdg16.04+1]
Remv postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3 [2.3.3+dfsg-1.pgdg16.04+1]
Remv python3-gdal [2.2.1+dfsg-2~xenial0]
Remv postgis [2.3.3+dfsg-1.pgdg16.04+1]
Remv python3-geopandas [0.1.1-3]
Remv python3-fiona [1.7.6-1~xenial1]
Remv libgdal1i [1.11.3+dfsg-3build2]
Remv qgis-providers [1:2.99.0+git20170820+f867b65+24xenial-ubuntugis]
...
Remv libgdal20 [2.2.1+dfsg-2~xenial0] [libqgis-core2.99.0:amd64 libqgis-customwidgets:amd64 liblas3:amd64 ]
Remv libqgispython2.99.0 [1:2.99.0+git20170820+f867b65+24xenial-ubuntugis] [libqgis-core2.99.0:amd64 libqgis-customwidgets:amd64 liblas3:amd64 ]
Remv libqgis-core2.99.0 [1:2.99.0+git20170820+f867b65+24xenial-ubuntugis] [libqgis-customwidgets:amd64 liblas3:amd64 ]
Remv python3-shapely [1.5.13-1build1] [libqgis-customwidgets:amd64 liblas3:amd64 ]
Remv libgeos-c1v5 [3.5.1-3~xenial0] [libsqlite3-mod-spatialite:amd64 libspatialite7:amd64 libqgis-customwidgets:amd64 liblas3:amd64 ]
Remv libgeos-3.5.1 [3.5.1-3~xenial0] [libsqlite3-mod-spatialite:amd64 libspatialite7:amd64 libqgis-customwidgets:amd64 liblas3:amd64 ]
Remv liblas-c3 [1.8.1-4~xenial1] [libsqlite3-mod-spatialite:amd64 libspatialite7:amd64 libqgis-customwidgets:amd64 liblas3:amd64 ]
Remv liblas3 [1.8.1-4~xenial1] [libsqlite3-mod-spatialite:amd64 libspatialite7:amd64 libqgis-customwidgets:amd64 ]
Remv libqgis-customwidgets [1:2.99.0+git20170820+f867b65+24xenial-ubuntugis] [libsqlite3-mod-spatialite:amd64 libspatialite7:amd64 ]
Remv libspatialite7 [4.3.0a-5] [libsqlite3-mod-spatialite:amd64 ]
Remv libsqlite3-mod-spatialite [4.3.0a-5]
```

I plan to also compile PostGIS from source, so that's not a problem.

But how can I keep other packages such as `qgis`, `gdal` etc. intact? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably accomplish what you want by keeping the system libraries and installing the new GEOS libs to a custom path. Only software that you explicitly tell about the new path will look there.

For example, when you build GEOS, you'll do something like:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL-PREFIX=/opt/blabla ..
make
make install
```

Then when you build, PostGIS, tell it to look in /opt/blabla for the GEOS includes and libs. If you want to run an already-built program using the new libs, set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to `/opt/blabla/lib` first.

Be careful, though. There have been some API changes between 3.5 (which is, I think, still current on Ubuntu) and 3.6 that may make the libs incompatible.